# Node.js fails to load blns.json file from BLNS repo

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to read blns.json from [this](https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings) repo.

I've tried `JSON.parse`, I've tried turning blns.json to blns.js and requiring the file through `module.exports`. I've even simply tried `console.log()` on the array and nothing:

```
Invalid or unexpected token
```

What is the best way to read this file in node to be consumed by my tests?

Comment: I see now the go implementation in the repo. I guess I would just need to translate that into node?

Comment: Consider editing your question title to something like "Node.js fails to load blns.json file from BLNS repo".

Answer (score 0):

The problem with *blns.json* file is in the fact that it contains bytes that do not conform with JSON (https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings/issues/20).

You can instead load [blns.base64.json](https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings/blob/master/blns.base64.json) which contains base64 representations of naughty strings and then decode them to Buffer (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding).

Keep in mind that if you will try to convert Buffers to Stings, then specific bytes will be lost and some strings will cease to be naughty. But if you are going to use *blns* to test a web app, then probably it does not matter.

Comment: thank you. would you mind elaborating on why this would not matter with a web app?

Comment: Because in the browser strings are JS Strings and not byte arrays as it usually happens in thin apps.